# What is the host of my docker image in macOS?

Tags: docker, ip-address

I have a server running in a docker image that's running in development. I looked up that `host.docker.internal` is supposed to resolve to the host of the docker image, but that's not the case. I'm getting "Connection refused" when making an http request from the parent machine that's running the docker container with `host.docker.internal`. How do I fix this?
And suppose I was running multiple docker images, how would the hosts for each be resolved differently?

Comment: What do you mean by "running with host.docker.internal"? And how is this related to programming?

Comment: by running with host.docker.internal, I mean making a get request from the parent machine with the hostname host.docker.internal

Comment: And what would you expect? I don't think that the Docker deamon provides a web interface

Comment: it might be easier if you used lando on your mac. Lando works with docker and makes configuring local development systems easier.

Comment: connect your container to host network and just use localhost:<port>. docker network connect host <containerId>. host.docker.internal used to be used when you wanted to connect to a container from another container locally.

Comment: Host networking does not work on Docker Desktop setups, either on MacOS or Windows.  It shouldn't be necessary for routine use, particularly since it disables all of Docker's networking functionality.

Comment: @AliMomeni, `running docker network connect host <containerID>` gives `endpoint with name <containerID> already exists in network host`. Despite this, `localhost:<port>` gives `connection refused`

Comment: @DavidMaze, is there any other ip that the docker image exposes that I can call from the parent environment?

Comment: have you used -p to map port to local port?